# Can I list all scenarios in capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

Can I list all scenarios so that I can view all scenarios easily?

Is there this command?

I didn't find that in the README and google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RSpec's --dry-run option print your suite's formatter output without running any examples or hooks (see the [Relish page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/dry-run-option)).

For example, to get an HTML page that shows all your scenarios:

```
rspec --dry-run -f html -o scenarios.htm
```